# Can my job offer be rescinded due to dates?

Tags: resume, job-offer, recruitment, work-experience, background-check

In December 2018, I left my most recent job at a bank.  Before doing so, I had been sending out a host of resumes, all of which said 2017-Present.

I also sent a resume to a friend to be referred to a company I had already replied to.  In Jan, I got a call from a recruiter about the company I applied to/my friend referred me to.  I went through a very long interview process, eventually recieving a job offer in April.

I was already offered the job and put the date that I left on the form for the background check.

Now, I'm going through the background check, which states all information must match the resume/company submitted profile.  The thing is, I never updated my resume.  I didn't lie about being at my old job during the interviews but I also never thought to send in a new resume, so I think people assumed I was.  What should I do?  I'm freaking out.

Comment: What would be the harm in simply checking with the recruiter, "Do you have my most up-to-date CV?" It was a long interview process after all, more than just your current job might have changed in that time.

Comment: Was your CV dated in any way? I put a current date on my CVs - you never know when an old one will resurface. Having said that I believe Sourav Ghosh's answer is correct and have upvoted it.

Comment: I was already offered the job and put the date that I left on the form for the background check.  However, during the job process, when I was asked why I was returning to consulting, I framed my answer to say how I missed that work, etc, etc and that, from my time at my old company, I didn't have the chance to work on projects I wanted.

Comment: At this point, I'm not even sure if its worth it to send an updated resume.  During the interview process, I never lied but I did frame my answers so that it might not have been clear I left my old job.

Comment: as P1 says, resumes are either explicitly dated, or "dated" the day they were sent. Of course, th info can only be correct as of the date of the resume.

Comment: The company uses Hireright and says that the background check form needs to match up perfectly with your resume, which is part of why I am freaking out.

Answer (score 9):

No need to freak out. At the point of sending out the resume, you held the position and the job. That should be proof enough for you.

Edit:

> *I was already offered the job and put the date that I left on the form for the background check.*

You did the correct thing. I'm reassuring you, nothing to be worried.

Comment: Agreed, it was correct at the time they received it. It would be beyond silly on their part to reject you now, having invested time and money in recruiting you, on the basis that you didn't continually supply them with a new CV any time anything changed.

Comment: But wouldn't it be bad that interviewers based their assumptions off my outdated resume?  I feel like I should just decline the offer and back out of the background check.

Comment: @ElizaK no you shouldn't, the only possible outcome from that is not getting the job. Stop freaking out. You listed a job as "until present" while you were working at that job, and that's fine. Anyone who doesn't understand that isn't worth working for, and they'll be in the minority, so don't shoot yourself in the foot here.

Comment: This is very helpful but I am worried that my last interview was in March, when I'd been gone from my job for threeish months.  My interviewer had my old resume which was outdated, obviously, at that point.  I just feel like it might be better to pull out rather than seem like a complete liar.  Also, my offer was really competitive-it's a consulting job and I was at an investment bank.  In retrospect, it feels like I wouldn't have gotten such a high offer had they known I left.

Comment: @ElizaK Always take an updated resume to every interview and provide it to them.

Comment: I know.  I did bring an updated resume to the one in person interview but I completely forgot to give it.  I'm so afraid I'll lose my chance because I realized there's a way to update your online application and I really wanted this company.  I might just withdraw before they rescind it.